# python lookup in csv

Tags: python, csv, ip-address, lookup

```
Child Block,Container
10.79.8.0/24,AT
10.80.0.64/26,DE
10.80.0.128/26,IT
10.80.0.192/26,DE
10.80.1.0/26,AT
10.80.1.64/26,FR
10.80.1.128/26,IT
10.80.1.192/26,AT
10.80.2.0/26,DE
10.80.2.64/26,FR
10.80.2.128/26,IT
10.80.2.192/26,AT
10.80.3.0/26,DE
10.80.3.64/26,AT
10.80.3.128/26,FR
```

inputs are 2 ip addresses (e.g.: 10.80.2.55 and 10.80.2.45) that code looks up in above list and if there are matches it returns with container strings (e.g.: DE FR).
however my code returns only one string DE or FR. How should i space the "for" loop to perform both lookup and return with both strings?

```
import csv
import sys
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress

try:
f = open('C:\\Users\\609593705\\test.csv', 'rt')
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
for row in reader:
    if IPAddress(sys.argv[1]) in IPNetwork(row['Child Block']):
        print (row['Container'])
        for row2 in reader:         
            if IPAddress(sys.argv[2]) in IPNetwork(row2['Child   Block']):        
                print (row2['Container'])

finally:
f.close()
```

Comment: what is `lookup(result[srcfield])`? You have no such function in your code.

Comment: sorry for that. corrected to "srclookup" and parameters as well.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using; as written this code would not run.

Comment: i posted the code i m working on.
i test it in command line: python ipreader.py 10.80.2.55 10.80.2.45
This return either DE or FR depending how much space i type for the seconf "for"